# Tracing a Specific Object Instance in iOS Instruments Tool

Tags: ios, object, instruments

I'm using the **Instruments** tool to track a bug I encountered in my application.

I've noticed while I'm running the app using the "Leak" tracker in Instruments, that I do have a leak at some point. Now I want to check exactly which object in the class responsible for allocating and releasing whatever needs to be released is leaking (the class has several elements in it that require alloc and release).

Is there a way to 'pin-point' a specific instance or at least object (similarly to what we have in the debugger where you can enter "self" while running and drop into its different objects)?